# Flex 4 - DataGrid with Button in cells

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, button, flex4

How can I add a button control in cells of a datagrid? I'm looking to have a button in each row of one column in the datagrid. The datagrid control rows don't need to be selectable in any way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really quite simple. Just define a custom item renderer for the column

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{this.someData}">
        <mx:columns>                
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Buttons" >
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:ItemRenderer width="100%">
                            <s:Button label="{data.buttonName}" click="{outerDocument.someFunction()}" />
                        </s:ItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
       </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

use `data` to refer to the row's dataprovider object and `outerDocument` to access methods outside of the item renderer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Flex 4 controls - ie. Spark use a GridItemRenderer.

There are very good examples here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridItemRenderer.html#includeExamplesSummary