# conditionally add an image to datagrid using an item renderer in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

I am adding an image to a cell of datagrid using an item renderer embedded in a data grid column. I need to add an image to a cell only if data from the row of the cell meets certain requirements. something like below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="delete" headerText="Delete" >
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[                                       
                            public function showImage():void{
                                if(rowData.column1 == "image1"){
                                    image1.visible = true;
                                }
                                else{
                                    image1.visible = false;
                                }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>
                    <mx:Image source="{image1}" visible="{showImage}"  id="deleteFile" click="" scaleX="0.1" scaleY="0.1" horizontalCenter="true" horizontalAlign="center"/>                                    
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here

Comment: how do I do this? the conditional statement is fine but how can i call this appropriately that an image will only show if the statement is met.

Comment: override `public function set data()` in your item renderer code add this in

Comment: ive added my complete code for the datagrid column above, could you elaborate on your previous comment. I'm a bit lost

Comment: I have elaborated below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to `<mx:Script>`

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    showImage();
}
```

`set data` is the function that the `grid` calls to do set up, this is the best function to override to apply conditional properties to the ItemRenderer

Comment: It this case it works but the best place to compute such things is not set data but commitProperties

Comment: your probably right, I've just been going off the Adobe doc's, which seem encourage set data

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
  <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="delete" headerText="Delete" >
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                <mx:Image source="{image1}" visible="{data.image1 == 'image1'}"  id="deleteFile" click="" scaleX="0.1" scaleY="0.1" horizontalCenter="true" horizontalAlign="center"/>                                    
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

But I encourage you to build a separate class and set it as itemRenderer for the Column.
Get more details on similar stackoverflow questions:

[How can I know when a Button in a Flex DataGrid itemRenderer is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099066/how-can-i-know-when-a-button-in-a-flex-datagrid-itemrenderer-is-clicked)

[Flex 4 - DataGrid with Button in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004841/flex-4-datagrid-with-button-in-cells)

Comment: isn't a binding risky since data could be set to null by the `dataProvider`?

Comment: @CyanAngel if dataProvider is null then there is no row inside the grid. So no need to call any of the renderers. Please try the sample and convince yourself that there is no runtime error.

Comment: Fair enough, same problem with with properties on untyped objects. But you've already addressed that by suggesting custom classes, which I whole heartedly agree with

Comment: @CyanAngel Yes, it would definitely be risky. A null check should be done regardless.

Answer (score 0):

CyanAngel is correct with comment about overriding `set data`

**Update** CityAngle just added the same answer as me, but I'll leave this here for posterity:-)

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
     super.data = value;

     if(value.column1 == "image1"){
            image1.visible = true;
     }
     else{
          image1.visible = false;
     }

}
```

`data` will be an object of they type that you have put in the DataGrids `dataProvider`.